# Code runs in PyCharm, ModuleNotFoundError from the terminal

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

It's not the first time I encounter this weird unexplained phenomenon of being unable to recognize packages in the terminal and being recognized in PyCharm and vice versa.

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
ticklab
├── __init__.py
├── extractors
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base_extractor.py
│   ├── extract.py
│   ├── polygon_cli.py
│   ├── polygon_extractor.py
│   └── stocks_debug.txt
└── logs
    └── extraction_session.log
```

in `polygon_extractor.py` I need to import `BaseExtractor` from `base_extractor`, so I do:

```
from extractors.base_extractor import BaseExtractor
```

it runs perfectly fine in PyCharm however when I do this in extractors directory

```
emadboctor@MacBook-Pro extractors % python3 polygon_extractor.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "polygon_extractor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from extractors.base_extractor import BaseExtractor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extractors'
```

So I added this under `main` guard and run from PyCharm

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Output:

```
/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/Code/ticklab
```

So I tried this from the terminal:

```
emadboctor@MacBook-Pro ticklab % python3 extractors/polygon_extractor.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extractors/polygon_extractor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from extractors.base_extractor import BaseExtractor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extractors'
emadboctor@MacBook-Pro ticklab %
```

There is a solution to the problem by changing the import statement to:

```
from base_extractor import BaseExtractor
```

It runs in both PyCharm and terminal but PyCharm code inspection cannot resolve `base_extractor`

[image: inspection]

When I change the import statement to:

```
from .base_extractor import BaseExtractor
```

It resolves and runs fine in PyCharm but gives the following error in terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "polygon_extractor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base_extractor import BaseExtractor
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Another solution is adding `sys.path.append('..')` but is also an unclean solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

try adding path `/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/Code/ticklab` as your PYTHONPATH environmental variable. You can use following command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/Code/ticklab
```

Comment: I can use `sys.path.append('..')` which will achieve the same thing and both are unclean solutions that are very likely to create problems in large codebases

Comment: @sK500 Take a look at official python documentation 
 https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH. PYTHONPATH is a pretty standard way of defining the location of your codebase. Python interpreter itself consults this variable for relative imports of modules.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code before importing the extractors
import os
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))
os.chdir(CURRENT_PATH)

Comment: You should never change the directory within a module, this is not a clean solution and as I said earlier the problem is solved using `sys.path.append('..')` and I'm not happy with this solution either